# Partial recursive set from values of recursive function

Tags: algorithms, computability

So I know that $E = \{n\ |\ \text{if } F(n,n) \text{ is defined}\}$, is recursively enumerable set which isn't recursive. But how i find a recursive function which values is that set?

Comment: Welcome to MSE ^_^. What is $F$?

Comment: F is a compatible for functions with 1 variable ( I used Google to translate this:) ). Its mean that for every f(x) there is such natural m for which F(m, x) = f(x)

Answer (score 1):

Fix some $m$ such that $F(m,m)$ is defined. Then define a function $g$ by setting
$$
g(n,s)=\begin{cases}
n&\text{if the computation of }F(n,n)\text{ produces an output in }<s\text{ steps.}\\
m&\text{otherwise.}
\end{cases}
$$
Then $g$ is recursive, and its range is your $E$.

Incidentally, I don't recall ever hearing "partial recursive set".  You probably meant "recursively enumerable set". Partial recursiveness is a property of functions, not of sets.

Comment: Yeah I meant enumerable set. Can I also use this function as E isn't empty there is always a b from E. And as E is recursively enumerable I can say there is  such a recursive  g(a,x) and E is those values of parameter a for which g(a,x) = 0 has solution. Then let t = c(a,x) and say f(t) = l(t) * not(sg(g(l(t), r(t))) +b * sg(g(l(t), r(t)). I think range of this function will be my E. I took this idea directly from the prrof that there is a such recursive function.

Comment: @Hov I imagine the $c,l,r$ in your comment refer to a pairing function, so they're essentially converting the binary function $g$  in my answer to a unary function. Apart from that, it seems that your $f$  and $g$ are essentially the $g$ and $F$ (respectively) in my answer (and in your question).